# Angular smart table without bower

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I want to use angular smart table library, but we are not using bower so I downloaded the files from github and I got the file "smart-table.min.js" and referenced it, I have no console errors but when I try to use smart table features such as paging, it's not working.

Do I have to add other files (CSS)??

```
<table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
                            <th st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
                            <th st-sort="birthDate">birth date</th>
                            <th st-sort="balance">balance</th>
                            <th>email</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
                            <td>{{row.firstName | uppercase}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.birthDate | date}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.balance | currency}}</td>
                            <td><a ng-href="mailto:{{row.email}}">email</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
                                    <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

Any help please

Comment: You need also add dependency for your module

Comment: I don't have package.json file

Comment: angular.module('yourModule', [.., 'smartTableModuleName'])

Answer (score 0):

In the ng-app definition, confirm you are referencing 'smart-table':

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'smart-table'
]);
```

In your controller, ensure you have "rowCollection" correctly defined:

```
$scope.rowCollection = [
{ firstName: "abc", lastName: "def", birthDate: "1/1/2010", balance: 0 },
{ firstName: "abc", lastName: "def", birthDate: "1/1/2010", balance: 0 },
{ firstName: "abc", lastName: "def", birthDate: "1/1/2010", balance: 0 }
]
```

As long as you have the correct smart table min.js file referenced, and appropriate angular.js version (1.5+), you should be gravy.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular/angular.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/smart-table/smart-table.min.js"></script>
```

If it still dont work, post up your full markup and we can help further.

Comment: Thank you, will check and get back to you